# Encoding a character

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-mvc-2, character-encoding

I am experiencing some weird encoding behaviour in my ASP.NET MVC project.

In my Site.Master there is

```
<div class="logo">
        <a href="<%=Url.Action("Index", "Win7")%>"><%= Html.Encode("Windows 7 Tutoriál") %></a></div>
```

which translates to the resulting page as

```
<div class="logo">
        <a href="/">Windows 7 TutoriĂˇl</a></div>
```

However, in the Index.aspx there is

```
<h1>
    Windows 7 Tutoriál</h1>
```

which translates correctly on the same resulting page.
I do have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

as my first line in `<head>`. Locally, both files are saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling `Html.Encode` when you output the text to the `h1`?

Comment: What encoding does your page/master page run on the server side? And if the string is constant "Windows 7 Tutoriál", do you really need the `Server.HtmlEncode()`?

Comment: No, I am not calling the Html.Encode on the other text, so was I originally not calling it on the first one, but out of desperation I tried it. There is no change regardless how do I apply the Encode method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm, I just found out, that both files are indeed in UTF-8, however, one of the was using version with signature while the other was without. I wonder when VS decided to change these. Thanks to commentators anyway.